# How can I persist Autofac graph across application startups?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, autofac

In Autofac, is there some way to cache the graph generated from the build configuration so that on subsequent application start it doesn't have to re-register everything?

In NHibernate I do something similar to prevent all my POCO objects from being re-mapped by serializing the generated configuration to disk and then deserializing it on startup. If I apply this same technique and attempt to serialize the `Container` object I get an exception stating that the `Container` class "is not marked as serializable".

Is there an alternative technique I could use for Autofac?

Comment: And why exactly is "re-registering everything" a problem and how would generating the graph be any different than "re-registering everything"?

Comment: I didn't say it was a problem per se. My aim was to make the start up process quicker and remove any unnecessary overhead. I assumed that it would be more efficient to serialize the graph/container to disk and then when the application restarts at a future point deserialize it instead of Autofac having to build the graph from scratch. Maybe my understanding is incorrect and maybe what I am trying to achieve is unnecessary but it would be nice to know if it's possible or appropriate and if not, why?

Comment: So you're having performance problems during application startup? Is the registration process too slow for you?

Comment: Let's say for arguments sake that the registration process time is reasonable (and that the registrations are already as efficient as possible) but I'm interested in improving it.

Comment: I'll just say this - you can't persist an application container (which would include all of the objects with all of their dependencies in their exact states all the way down the graph) across application restarts, so you'll need to solve the app startup challenge in a different way.